# RYO blog engine - showing tags for several posts

Tags: perl, sqlite, dancer

I am writing yet another blog engine for practice, using SQLite and Perl Dancer framework.

The tables go like this:

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
    p_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    p_url VARCHAR(255),
    p_title VARCHAR(255),
    p_text TEXT,
    p_date DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE tags (
    t_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    t_tag VARCHAR(255),
    t_url VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE tags_posts_junction (
    tp_tag INTEGER NOT NULL,
    tp_post INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(tp_tag) REFERENCES tags.t_id,
    FOREIGN KEY(tp_post) REFERENCES tags.p_id
);
```

All the big guys like Wordpress (or stackoverflow) can show tags right on the main page, after each question, and I'd like to implement it too. The question is how do I do it.

So far the posts are stored in the database, and when I need to render a page showing latest 20 posts I pass a hash refernece (`fetchall_hashref` from `DBI`) to the template. So how do I add tags there? Of course I can do something like

```
my $dbh = database->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY p_date DESC 
                    LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0');
$dbh->execute;
my $posts = $dbh->fetchall_hashref('p_date');
foreach my $key (keys $post) {
    my $dbh = database->prepare('SELECT * FROM tags WHERE t_id IN (
                    SELECT tp_tag FROM tags_posts_junction WHERE tp_post = ?)');
    $dbh->execute($post->{"$key"}->{"p_id"});
    my $tags = $dbh->fetchall_hashref(t_id);
    $post->{"$key"}->{"$tag_hash"} = $tags;
};
```

But that's ugly and that's 20 more queries per page, isn't it too much? I think there should be a better way.

So the question is how do I get tags for 20 posts the least redundant way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collect all the p_ids into an array and construct your query using IN instead of =, something like this, presuming @pids is your array:

```
my $dbh = database->prepare('SELECT * FROM tags WHERE t_id IN (
                    SELECT tp_tag FROM tags_posts_junction WHERE tp_post IN (' .
                    join(', ', ('?')x@pids).') )');
$dbh->execute(@pids);
```

Though you should really look to JOINs to replace your sub-queries.

Comment: That query would give me an array of all tags present on the page, wouldn't it? And I'm afraid a join would give me carthesian product, which I don't want.

Comment: Indeed, JOIN works just fine and your code example is very helpful. Thanks a lot, the query for this question would be something like `SELECT p_date, t_url, t_name FROM posts JOIN tags_posts_junction ON p_id = tp_post JOIN tags ON t_id = tp_tag WHERE p_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4);`

Answer (score 1):

I think you could combine your first / outer query before

```
my $posts = $dbh->fetchall_hashref('p_date');
```

with your inner query and then you will be hitting the database once instead of 20 times.

You could also simplify your code by use of DBIx::Simple - https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx::Simple.

Putting this together would give something like:

```
my $sql =   'SELECT t.*, p.*
             FROM tags t 
             JOIN tags_posts_junction tpj ON t.t_tag = tpj.t_tag
             JOIN posts p ON p.p_id = tpj.tp_post
             WHERE tpj.tp_post IN (
                SELECT p_id FROM posts ORDER BY p_date DESC 
                LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
              )';
my $db = DBIx::Simple->connect($dbh);
my $posts = $db->query($sql)->hashes;
```

Comment: Added the query, the combining examble would be just great, as for DBIx:Simple - not sure I have a corresponding Dancer plugin, and anyway, I think I should keep raw SQL for now since it's more a learning project than anything else. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I also think I could query `tags` and `tags_post_junction` tables and process the output in the application. It's three queries, but still not 20.

Comment: You shouldn't need a plugin for DBIx::Simple, just pass in your existing $dbh to the DBIx-Simple connect method.

Comment: I'll come back when I have more rep and vote up this one, `DBIx::Simple` is a very nice thing.